# Can't access WP site over WiFi network

Tags: htaccess, server, localhost

I'm making a mobile site and I'm using the main computers IP adress to connect to it from the iphone `10.0.0.1/wp`

With normal sites it works fine, but the WP site I get is stripped from CSS, JS, and images, only plain text. on the mac and the iphone-simulator it works fine.

Is it something known and configurable?

Comment: Can you access the site by typing in the same IP address on the server, eg. "http://10.0.0.1/wp/"?

Comment: @MiljenkoBarbir Yes, it works fine with ip from the same computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it because wordpress use the server address from database `get_option('siteurl')` and `get_option('home')`, so if you access the wordpress from IP Address the assets (js and css) will still loaded from `localhost/wp/` that mean from `127.0.0.1` not the `10.0.0.1`

the simple way to get dynamic url for your wordpress is defining the site_url and home_url on wp-config.php with function that parse the request and get the correct root url for your wordpress

try to add this script below the

`/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');`

```
/**
 * get home url from absolute path
 * @return string url to main site
 * lafif@astahdziq.in
 */
function get_dynamic_home_url(){
    $base_dir  = ABSPATH; // Absolute path
    $doc_root  = preg_replace("!${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}$!", '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
    $base_url  = preg_replace("!^${doc_root}!", '', $base_dir);
    $protocol  = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https';
    $port      = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    $disp_port = ($protocol == 'http' && $port == 80 || $protocol == 'https' && $port == 443) ? '' : ":$port";
    $domain    = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $home_url  = "${protocol}://${domain}${disp_port}${base_url}";

    return $home_url;
}
$url = get_dynamic_home_url();
define('WP_SITEURL', $url);
define('WP_HOME', $url);
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be a conflict between the internal option `'home'` or `'siteurl'` and the access per pure IP address. WordPress doesn’t use just any server name, there is some redundancy which may get in your way here.

You can try to resolve that by two constants defined in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
// or
// define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp' );

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
// or
// define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp' );
```

These constants should outdo the options from the database.

Comment: This is almost certainly the right answer. Odds are, your CSS/JS/IMAGES are not being "stripped", but are being referenced using whatever domain the site is assigned to on your computer (which your phone can't access properly, but your computer can--which is why it appears to work on your computer via the IP). As an additional note, if you have images embedded in any of your posts, they won't be visible on your phone, even if you implement toscho's fix, as they'll have the domain hardcoded.

Comment: @MathSmath Yeah, you’ll need probably a filter for the whole output and strip or replace the server name from all paths. I _think_ I have written a plugin for that, just can’t find it right now.